# how to authenticate user in chrome extension once authenticated on the server and the browser using google oauth2

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, redux, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I have a basic MERN app that uses google oauth2 passport strategy for authentication. I am making a google chrome extension to support my react app.
I want the google chrome extension to get authenticated as soon as the react app gets authenticated. Is there a way to do this ?. currently I am using react-chrome-redux to maintain the same state across tabs. How do I communicate to the chrome extension once the auth flow on my client side ends ?

Comment: [Sending messages from web pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage).

Comment: So I should setup a content script that updates the state on the login success page. ??

Comment: The article I've linked says your web page app can send a message to your extension (usually to its script declared in manifest.json as "background").